# How to inherit from a multiprocessing queue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing

With the following code, it seems that the queue instance passed to the worker isn't initialized:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue

class MyQueue(Queue):

    def __init__(self, name):
        Queue.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

def worker(queue):
    print queue.name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = MyQueue("My Queue")
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

This throws:

```
... line 14, in worker
    print queue.name
AttributeError: 'MyQueue' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I can't re-initialize the queue, because I'll loose the original value of queue.name, even passing the queue's name as an argument to the worker (this should work, but it's not a clean solution).

So, how can inherit from multiprocessing.queues.Queue without getting this error?

Comment: What platform is this on? On POSIX, it should definitely work. On Windows… I don't remember how multiprocessing fakes inheriting queues in child processes, but it involves some trickery, so I wouldn't be too surprised if it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On POSIX, `Queue` objects are shared to the child processes by simple inheritance.*

On Windows, that isn't possible, so it has to pickle the `Queue`, send it over a pipe to the child, and unpickle it.

(This may not be obvious, because if you actually try to pickle a `Queue`, you get an exception, `RuntimeError: MyQueue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`. If you look through the source, you'll see that this is really a lie—it only raises this exception if you try to pickle a `Queue` when `multiprocess` is not in the middle of spawning a child process.)

Of course generic pickling and unpickling wouldn't do any good, because you'd end up with two identical queues, not the same queue in two processes. So, `multiprocessing` extends things a bit, by adding a `register_after_fork` mechanism for objects to use when unpickling.** If you look at [the source for `Queue`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py#l56), you can see how it works.

But you don't really need to know *how* it works to hook it; you can hook it the same way as any other class's pickling. For example, this should work:***

```
def __getstate__(self):
    return self.name, super(MyQueue, self).__getstate__()

def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.name, state = state
    super(MyQueue, self).__setstate__(state)
```

For more details, the [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) documentation explains the different ways you can influence how your class is pickled.

(If it doesn't work, and I haven't made a stupid mistake… then you *do* have to know at least a little about how it works to hook it… but most likely just to figure out whether to do your extra work before or after the `_after_fork()`, which would just require swapping the last two lines…)

---

* I'm not sure it's actually guaranteed to use simple fork inheritance on POSIX platforms. That happens to be true on 2.7 and 3.3. But there's a fork of `multiprocessing` that uses the Windows-style pickle-everything on all platforms for consistency, and another one that uses a hybrid on OS X to allow using `CoreFoundation` in single-threaded mode, or something like that, and it's clearly doable that way.

** Actually, I *think* `Queue` is only using `register_after_fork` for convenience, and could be rewritten without it… but it's depending on the magic that `Pipe` does in its `_after_fork` on Windows, or `Lock` and `BoundedSemaphore` on POSIX.

*** This is only correct because I happen to know, from reading the source, that `Queue` is a new-style class, doesn't override `__reduce__` or `__reduce_ex`, and never returns a falsey value from `__getstate__`. If you didn't know that, you'd have to write more code.

Comment: Perfect! It works. I'll read about this, to know how the code works :-). Yes, I forgot to say that I'm running on Windows. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cdonts: Learning how to customize `pickle` feels tremendously complicated when you're reading the docs… but once you start playing with it, it really isn't. Learning how `multiprocessing` works under the hood, on the other hand… if you really want to, I'd recommend learning 3.4, not 2.7, because it really _is_ complicated, and when you find something that looks odd, it could easily be a bug or mistake that has been fixed but hasn't been backported to 2.x…

Comment: Good. Thanks for the data!