# How to inherit from multiprocessing.Pipe?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to build a wrapper class around the Python's `multiprocessing.Pipe` object. Inheriting from the `multiprocessing` module is known to have its challenges (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906575/how-to-inherit-from-a-multiprocessing-queue) for a similar question discussing inheritance for `multiprocessing.Queue`), and I'm facing an error I can't resolve.

Let's consider a simple example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pipe


class MyClass1: pass


class MyClass2(Pipe, MyClass1):
    pass
```

Here we create a class `MyClass2` that inherits both from the Pipe class and from a custom class `MyClass1`. Running the above will raise

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class
 must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I know that to solve this error I will likely have to introduce a metaclass that `MyClass2` can inherit from, but when I try to determine the metaclass of the `Pipe` object using `type(Pipe)` I get `<class 'type'>` which doesn't help at all.

The Stack Overflow questions I linked to above mentions that there is essentially a special way to inherit `Queue`. Is there also a special way for `Pipe`? Any suggestions on how to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Pipe` class. It works for `multiprocessing.Queue` because there is a `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` class, but `multiprocessing.Pipe` is just backed by another `Pipe` function in `multiprocessing.connection.py`.

You are trying to inherit from a function which always returns *two* connection objects. You would rather have to subclass the various connections objects `Pipe` can return. What connection objects this will be is OS-dependent and dependent on if the connection should be duplex/simplex. I doubt that would be a good idea, though. (Take a look at `multiprocessing.connection.py` to get cured from that idea ;)

I would suggest to make your own `MyPipe` function, let it call `multiprocessing.Pipe` internally and let it append, whatever you need, to the returned connection objects.

Answer (score 0):

From python documentation. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html

> The Pipe() function returns a pair of connection objects connected by a pipe which by default is duplex (two-way).

`Pipe` is a method and therefore you cannot inherit from it.

Comment: As described in the linked question, `mp.Queue` is a method but there exists `mp.queues.Queue` which is an inheritable object. I'm wondering if an analogous class exists for `mp.Pipe`.

Comment: You should check those docs I linked. Queue is, in fact, a class. It is not a method.